# any workaround to do forward forecasting for estimating time series in python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, time-series

I want to make forward forecasting for monthly times series of air pollution data such as what would be 3~6 months ahead of estimation on air pollution index. I tried `scikit-learn` models for forecasting and fitting data to the model works fine. But what I wanted to do is making a forward period estimate such as what would be 6 months ahead of the air pollution output index is going to be. In my current attempt, I could able to train the model by using `scikit-learn`. But I don't know how that forward forecasting can be done in python. To make a forward period estimate, what should I do? Can anyone suggest a possible workaround to do this? Any idea?

**my attempt**

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing StandardScaler
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.linear_model import BayesianRidge

url = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jerry-shad/36912907ba8660e11cd27be0d3e30639/raw/424f0891dc46d96cd5f867f3d2697777ac984f68/pollution.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(url, parse_dates=['dates'])
df.drop(columns=['Unnamed: 0'], inplace=True)

resultsDict={}
predictionsDict={}

split_date ='2017-12-01'
df_training = df.loc[df.index <= split_date]
df_test = df.loc[df.index > split_date]

df_tr = df_training.drop(['pollution_index'],axis=1)
df_te = df_test.drop(['pollution_index'],axis=1)

scaler = StandardScaler() 
scaler.fit(df_tr)
X_train = scaler.transform(df_tr)  
y_train = df_training['pollution_index']
X_test = scaler.transform(df_te)
y_test = df_test['pollution_index']
X_train_df = pd.DataFrame(X_train,columns=df_tr.columns)
X_test_df = pd.DataFrame(X_test,columns=df_te.columns)

reg = linear_model.BayesianRidge()
reg.fit(X_train, y_train)
yhat = reg.predict(X_test)
resultsDict['BayesianRidge'] = accuracy_score(df_test['pollution_index'], yhat)
```

**new update 2**

this is my attempt using ARMA model

```
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA

index = len(df_training)
yhat = list()
for t in tqdm(range(len(df_test['pollution_index']))):
    temp_train = df[:len(df_training)+t]
    model = ARMA(temp_train['pollution_index'], order=(1, 1))
    model_fit = model.fit(disp=False)
    predictions = model_fit.predict(start=len(temp_train), end=len(temp_train), dynamic=False)
    yhat = yhat + [predictions]
    
yhat = pd.concat(yhat)
resultsDict['ARMA'] = evaluate(df_test['pollution_index'], yhat.values)
```

but this can't help me to make forward forecasting of estimating my time series data. what I want to do is, what would be 3~6 months ahead of estimated values of pollution_index. Can anyone suggest me a possible workaround to do this? How to overcome the limitation of my current attempt? What should I do? Can anyone suggest me a better way of doing this? Any thoughts?

**update: goal**

for the clarification, I am not expecting which model or approach works best, but what I am trying to figure it out is, how to make reliable forward forecasting for given time series (pollution index), how should I correct my current attempt if it is not efficient and not ready to do forward period estimation. Can anyone suggest any possible way to do this?

**update-desired output**

here is my sketch desired forecasting plot that I want to make:

[image]

Comment: ARIMA(x), exponential smoothing, boosted trees or recurrent NN for detrended data, model ensembles. Google Time series forecasting

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov I did deseasoning and detrending, but still not sure how to make my current attempt right for forward period estimation. Could you elaborate on your point if it is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to obtain your desired output, I think you need to use a model that can return the standard deviation in the predicted value. Therefore, I adopt Gaussian process regression. From the code you provided in your post, I don't see how this is a time series forecasting task, so in my solution below, I also treat this task as a usual regression task.

First, prepare the data

```
import pandas 
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor


url = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jerry-shad/36912907ba8660e11cd27be0d3e30639/raw/424f0891dc46d96cd5f867f3d2697777ac984f68/pollution.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(url,parse_dates=['date'])
df.drop(columns=['Unnamed: 0'],axis=1,inplace=True)

# sort the dataframe by date and reset the index 
df = df.sort_values(by='date').reset_index(drop=True)
# after sorting the dataframe, split the dataframe
split_date ='2017-12-01'
df_training = df.loc[(df.date <= split_date).values]
df_test = df.loc[(df.date > split_date).values]
# drop the date column 
df_training.drop(columns=['date'],axis=1,inplace=True)
df_test.drop(columns=['date'],axis=1,inplace=True)

y_train = df_training['pollution_index']
y_test = df_test['pollution_index']
df_training.drop(['pollution_index'],axis=1)
df_test.drop(['pollution_index'],axis=1)

scaler = StandardScaler() 
scaler.fit(df_training)
X_train = scaler.transform(df_training)  
X_test = scaler.transform(df_test)

X_train_df = pd.DataFrame(X_train,columns=df_training.columns)
X_test_df = pd.DataFrame(X_test,columns=df_test.columns)
```

with the dataframes prepared above, you can train a `GaussianProcessRegressor` and make predictions by

```
gpr = GaussianProcessRegressor(normalize_y=True).fit(X_train_df,y_train)
pred,std = gpr.predict(X_test_df,return_std=True)
```

in which `std` is an array of standard deviations in the predicted values. Then, you can plot the data by

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 


fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))

plot_start = 225
# plot the training data 
ax.plot(y_train.index[plot_start:],y_train.values[plot_start:],'navy',marker='o',label='observed')
# plot the test data
ax.plot(y_test.index,y_test.values,'navy',marker='o')
ax.plot(y_test.index,pred,'darkgreen',marker='o',label='pred')

sigma = np.sqrt(std)
ax.fill(np.concatenate([y_test.index,y_test.index[::-1]]),
        np.concatenate([pred-1.960*sigma,(pred+1.9600*sigma)[::-1]]),
        alpha=.5,fc='silver',ec='tomato',label='95% confidence interval')

ax.legend(loc='upper left',prop={'size':16})
```

the output plot looks like

[image: output]

---

**UPDATE**

I thought `pollution_index` is something that can be predicted by `'dew', 'temp', 'press', 'wnd_spd', 'rain'`. If you want a one-step ahead forecasting, here is what you can do

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.dates as mdates


url = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jerry-shad/36912907ba8660e11cd27be0d3e30639/raw/424f0891dc46d96cd5f867f3d2697777ac984f68/pollution.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(url,parse_dates=['date'])
df.drop(columns=['Unnamed: 0'],axis=1,inplace=True)

# sort the dataframe by date and reset the index 
df = df.sort_values(by='date').reset_index(drop=True)
# after sorting the dataframe, split the dataframe
split_date ='2017-12-01'
df_training = df.loc[(df.date <= split_date).values]
df_test = df.loc[(df.date > split_date).values]
# extract the relevant info
train_date,train_polltidx = df_training['date'].values,df_training['pollution_index'].values
test_date,test_polltidx = df_test['date'].values,df_test['pollution_index'].values

# train an ARIMA model
model = ARIMA(train_polltidx,order=(1,1,1))
model_fit = model.fit(disp=0)
# you can predict as many as you want, here I only predict len(test_dat.index) days 
forecast,stderr,conf = model_fit.forecast(len(test_date))

# plot the result
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))
plot_start = 225
# plot the training data 
plt.plot(train_date[plot_start:],train_polltidx[plot_start:],'navy',marker='o',label='observed')
# plot the test data
plt.plot(test_date,test_polltidx,'navy',marker='o')
plt.plot(test_date,forecast,'darkgreen',marker='o',label='pred')
# ax.errorbar(np.arange(len(pred)),pred,std,fmt='r')

plt.fill(np.concatenate([test_date,test_date[::-1]]),
         np.concatenate((conf[:,0],conf[:,1][::-1])),
         alpha=.5,fc='silver',ec='tomato',label='95% confidence interval')
plt.legend(loc='upper left',prop={'size':16})
ax = plt.gca()

ax.set_xlim([df_training['date'].values[plot_start],df_test['date'].values[-1]])
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(interval=6))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

The output figure is

[image: output]

Clearly, the prediction is very bad, because I haven't done any preprocessing to the training data.

---

**UPDATE 2**

Since I'm not familiar with `ARIMA`, I implement one-step forecasting using `GaussianProcessRegressor` with the help of [this wonderful post](https://machinelearningmastery.com/xgboost-for-time-series-forecasting/).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

url = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jerry-shad/36912907ba8660e11cd27be0d3e30639/raw/424f0891dc46d96cd5f867f3d2697777ac984f68/pollution.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(url,parse_dates=['date'])
df.drop(columns=['Unnamed: 0'],axis=1,inplace=True)

# sort the dataframe by date and reset the index 
df = df.sort_values(by='date').reset_index(drop=True)
# after sorting the dataframe, split the dataframe
split_date ='2017-12-01'
df_training = df.loc[(df.date <= split_date).values]
df_test = df.loc[(df.date > split_date).values]

# extract the relevant info
train_date,train_polltidx = df_training['date'].values,df_training['pollution_index'].values[:,None]
test_date,test_polltidx = df_test['date'].values,df_test['pollution_index'].values[:,None]
# preprocessing 
scalar = StandardScaler()
scalar.fit(train_polltidx)
train_polltidx = scalar.transform(train_polltidx)
test_polltidx = scalar.transform(test_polltidx)


def series_to_supervised(data,n_in,n_out):

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    cols = list()
    for i in range(n_in,0,-1): cols.append(df.shift(i))
    for i in range(0, n_out): cols.append(df.shift(-i))
    agg = pd.concat(cols,axis=1)
    agg.dropna(inplace=True)

    return agg.values

months_look_back = 1
# train 
pollt_series = series_to_supervised(train_polltidx,months_look_back,1)
x_train,y_train = pollt_series[:,:months_look_back],pollt_series[:,-1]
# test
pollt_series = series_to_supervised(test_polltidx,months_look_back,1)
x_test,y_test = pollt_series[:,:months_look_back],pollt_series[:,-1]
print("The first %i months in the test set won't be predicted." % months_look_back)

def walk_forward_validation(x_train,y_train,x_test,y_test):
    
    predictions = []
    history_x = x_train.tolist()
    history_y = y_train.tolist()
    
    for rep,target in zip(x_test,y_test):
        # train model 
        gpr = GaussianProcessRegressor(alpha=1e-4,normalize_y=False).fit(history_x,history_y)
        pred,std = gpr.predict([rep],return_std=True)
        
        predictions.append([pred,std])
        history_x.append(rep)
        history_y.append(target)
        
    return predictions

predictions = walk_forward_validation(x_train,y_train,x_test,y_test)
pred_test,pred_std = zip(*predictions)

# put back
pred_test = scalar.inverse_transform(pred_test)
pred_std = scalar.inverse_transform(pred_std)
train_polltidx = scalar.inverse_transform(train_polltidx)
test_polltidx = scalar.inverse_transform(test_polltidx)

# plot the result
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))
plot_start = 100 
# plot the training data 
plt.plot(train_date[plot_start:],train_polltidx[plot_start:],'navy',marker='o',label='observed')
# plot the test data
plt.plot(test_date[months_look_back:],test_polltidx[months_look_back:],'navy',marker='o')
plt.plot(test_date[months_look_back:],pred_test,'darkgreen',marker='o',label='pred')

sigma = np.sqrt(pred_std)
ax.fill(np.concatenate([test_date[months_look_back:],test_date[months_look_back:][::-1]]),
        np.concatenate([pred_test-1.960*sigma,(pred_test+1.9600*sigma)[::-1]]),
        alpha=.5,fc='silver',ec='tomato',label='95% confidence interval')
plt.legend(loc='upper left',prop={'size':16})
ax = plt.gca()

ax.set_xlim([df_training['date'].values[plot_start],df_test['date'].values[-1]])
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(interval=6))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

The idea of this script is to cast the time series forecasting task into a supervised regression task. The `plot_start` is a parameter that controls from which year we want to plot, clearly `plot_start` cannot be greater than the length of the training data. The output figure of the script is

[image: output]

as you can see, the first month in the test dataset is not predicted, because we need to look back one month to make a prediction.

In order to further make predictions about unseen data, based on [this post on CV site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/346196/198896), you can train a new model using the predicted value from the last step, therefore, here is how you can do it

```
unseen_dates = pd.date_range(test_date[-1],periods=180,freq='D').values
all_data = series_to_supervised(df['pollution_index'].values,months_look_back,months_to_predict)

def predict_unseen(unseen_dates,all_data,days_look_back):
    
    predictions = []
    history_x = all_data[:,:days_look_back].tolist()
    history_y = all_data[:,-1].tolist()
    inds = np.arange(unseen_dates.shape[0])
    
    for ind in inds:
        # train model 
        gpr = GaussianProcessRegressor(alpha=1e-2,normalize_y=False).fit(history_x,history_y)
        rep = np.array(history_y[-days_look_back:]).reshape(days_look_back,1)
        pred,std = gpr.predict(rep,return_std=True)
        
        predictions.append([pred,std])
        history_x.append(history_y[-days_look_back:])
        history_y.append(pred)
        
    return predictions

predictions = predict_unseen(unseen_dates,all_data,days_look_back=1)
pred_test,pred_std = zip(*predictions)

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))
plot_start = 100 
# plot the test data
plt.plot(unseen_dates,pred_test,'navy',marker='o')
sigma = np.sqrt(pred_std)
ax.fill(np.concatenate([unseen_dates,unseen_dates[::-1]]),
        np.concatenate([pred_test-1.960*sigma,(pred_test+1.9600*sigma)[::-1]]),
        alpha=.5,fc='silver',ec='tomato',label='95% confidence interval')
plt.legend(loc='upper left',prop={'size':16})
ax = plt.gca()

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=7))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

[image: output]

One very important thing to note: The timestep of the real data is a month, using such data to make predictions about days may not be correct.

Comment: thanks for your output. How can we make one-step ahead forecasting such as 3 months ahead prediction, like [this one](https://ibb.co/sJB6kWm)? I was thinking of function something like `forecast_model(test_data, freq='D', prediction_length=180)` but still not getting right about it. Do you have any possible update?

Comment: also in the above plot, why x-axis is not about the date? can we come up something like `forecast_model(test_data['pollution_index'], freq='D', prediction_length=180)`? Any more thoughts? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @kim You're welcome, check out my updated post, I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: thanks again. you are right, we can think of pollution_index is something that can be predicted by 'dew', 'temp', 'press', 'wnd_spd', 'rain'; I think there is few things to do with preprocessing. If that so, why we have very unusual prediction output? Do you think it that doable something like `forecast_model(test_data, freq='D', prediction_length=180)`? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @kim You're welcome :) It is doable, check out my updated post :)

Comment: thanks again for the update :). One more question, can we make 3 months ahead forecasting for `pollution_index` like including `2020-11-01` to `2021-03-01` in your update attempt? How can we do that? Any idea? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @kim You're welcome :) I have updated my post, in which I shared an approach to make predictions about unseen data. I don't know why `plot_start=100 or 200` will cause the problem, I have tried `100`, and it works fine. As for why `300` and `400` are not working, the reason is the two numbers are greater than the length of `train_date` , which is a `(257,)` array.

Answer (score 0):

The model you have built links what you are trying to model, 'pollution_index', to some input variables, in your case `['dew', 'temp', 'press', 'wnd_spd', 'rain']`. So to predict pollution_index into the future using your model, at the high level, you need to estimate what these variables would be over the next 3-6 months, and then run your model on that. Practically, you need to come up with something that looks like X_test but has *your* projections for these variables for the future, and then call:

`yhat = reg.predict(X_test)`

... to produce the model estimate of where the pollution_index will be. Hope this makes sense. This gives you a "mechanical" ability to use your model for prediction.

For example, following up on your main example where `reg` is `BayesianRidge()` that you fit, we would do the following:

```
import sys
from io import StringIO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Here we load your predictions for input variables
# I stubbed it with some random data
df_predict_data = StringIO(
"""
date,dew,temp,press,wnd_spd,rain
2021-01-01,59,28,16,0.78,98.7
2021-02-01,68,32,18,0.79,46.1
2021-03-01,75,34,20,0.81,91.5
2021-04-01,63,31,16,0.83,19.1
2021-05-01,74,38,19,0.83,21.8
2021-06-01,65,32,17,0.85,35.4
""")

df_predict = pd.read_csv(df_predict_data, index_col = 'date')

# scale it using the same scaler you used in training
X_predict = scaler.transform(df_predict)

# predict pollution_index
y_predict = reg.predict(X_predict)

#  plot it
plt.plot(df_predict.index, y_predict, '.-')
```

So we get this:

[image]

Whether the linear regression you built is a good model for such prediction is a completely different question. As @Sergey Bushmanov mentioned there is vast literature on forecasting and what models are best for this or that, and this thread is probably not the right place to debate that aspect of your question.

Comment: I am not asking what model best, what I am asking how to make forward period estimation either using scikit-learn or ARMA. I gave enough amount of code for my attempt. Do you have a possible coding attempt that might be helpful?

Comment: fair enough. I edited the answer to show the bit of code that would generate prediction of pollution_index from your estimate of other variables. this is for BayessianRidge() fit

Comment: well you asked how to use the model you trained on historical data to predict future values of pollution_index, and this is what I explained

Comment: well, I am not convinced with your posted answer because it is not constructive and solid, it can't be a canonical answer to assign a bounty score for now.

Comment: @piterbarg why do you construct `df_predict_data` like that? Your answer is still not clear enough though.

Comment: @beyond_infinity, to predict an output variable of a model, once you trained it, you need to supply it with input variables. So once you linked pollution_index to rain etc, you need to specify what your rain etc going to be in the future in order to predict pollution_index in the future.

Comment: I am not sure I can say it any more clearly than above, and I already said it a few times. Perhaps an analogy with image recognition would help. If you trained a Neural Network to classify images as 'cat' or 'dog', you need to show an image to you model for it to say it is a cat or a dog! it cannot just give you the output (cat or dog) without you feeding it an image. same here. you want a prediction of pollution_index? feed the model the input variables it expects

Comment: @kim, even though the answer of OP is not satisfying you.. its an answer. It would help to point in the direction of how the answer should evolve. Regardless, if OP is pointing you in more or less the correct direction "I as user" would be grateful. Most questions on SO are not answer this quickly; or even at all.

Comment: @kim also... I am counting more than five question-marks where less is acceptable (read: focus). Perhaps down-tuning your question will help this OP or another answering it more focused? The answer is not about getting the rep bounty. Its an user trying to help you out. Keep in mind that nobody can force you to reward the rep. But... if any OP really puts you in the right direction (not saying piterbarg is "the" OP) you should consider rewarding the bonus anyway. It boost moral.. and 6 days is a lot of time to get even better or more answers that help you or OP to a fitting answer ;-)

Comment: @kim... merely reviewing your question and OPs answer as they both did get flagged for various reasons. Looks okay to me. EoR.

Comment: @ZF007 but the posted answer is not actually answering OP. Did I ask the wrong question or my OP is too confusing and broad? what I asked there is only one problem and the posted answer is not hitting the question that I raised. Do I have to accept the answer even it is clearly wrong? I followed `SO` rule. Only the answer that hit the OP should be accepted.

Comment: @kim there is no need to accept any answer as the question bouty period ends in 6 days. Less questions in a question gives better result. With current knowledge you might need to bring more focus in your question or add additional information to get the focus? I'm not going into checking all or current answer details (fixing references in a GUI atm.). After six days you can see if there is an answer that fits better to your question. If none provides the desired result you can decide not to award the bounty. But as explained.. even if its 75% correct you may consider awarding it.

Comment: @kim you can also point OP in  the right direction or post your own solution. But if its based on a previous posted answer I would mention that in my own posted answer. Credits to whom it deserve. I hope this explanation helps you in your decision in 6 days from now.(now back to code checking for a bit).